# How can I present a custom view modally without using presentViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Is it possible to present a view controller modally using `addChildViewController`? I want to present a `UIviewcontroller's` view modally so it overlaps any views under the window hierarchy. I want to do it without using the `self.presentViewcontroller` because I want to build **my own animation** instead of using the preset flip up/down/ etc. I tried using the `self.addChildViewcontroller(modal)` and `self.view.addSubView(modal.view)` but it goes inside my `ChildViewController`. When I used `self.view.window?.addSubview`, the app crashes.

Is it possible to present a UIViewcontroller modally using `addChildController`?

I included my sample codes.

https://github.com/cuongta/testcode

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   var childVC = ChildViewController()
   var navVC = UINavigationController()
   navVC.viewControllers = [childVC]
   self.addChildViewController(navVC)
   self.view.addSubview(navVC.view)
}
```

Comment: Could you post crashing code snippet here and pinpoint the error messages? It would be easier to help you instead downloading project from somewhere

Comment: you can use UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning,UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate class to make ur own custom animation and use presentViewcontroller

Comment: you can also check this: https://github.com/nferocious76/TestModal 
i didn't use the default presentation call that apple provided just a simple animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` and `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` to achieve what you want.

I think it's the best way according to *Apple*.

> Adopt the UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol in objects
> that implement the animations for a **custom view controller transition**.
>
> The methods in this protocol let you define an animator object, which
> creates the animations for transitioning a view controller on or off
> screen in a fixed amount of time. The animations you create using this
> protocol must not be interactive. To create interactive transitions,
> you must combine your animator object with another object that
> controls the timing of your animations.

You can download an *Apple Sample Code* [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/LookInside/Introduction/Intro.html)